# Passing template class object to thread initializer function, throws errors but works with lambda

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20

I am unable to understand why passing template class object as parameter to function, for thread initialization is erroring out. The function normally works, as well as the same expression works with lamdba too. C++17.

```
    template<typename T>
class TestTemp {
    T _val;
    public:
        TestTemp(T val):_val(val)
        {}
        
        void print()
        {
            std::cout<<_val<<std::endl;
        }
};

template<typename T>
void function(TestTemp<T> &nums)
{
    nums.print();
}

int main()
{
    TestTemp<int> t(100);
    function(t); //works 
    
    std::thread t2([&](){ t.print(); }); //works as well
    t2.join();
    
    std::thread t1(function, std::ref(t)); // errors out
    t1.join();
    
    return 0;
}
```

''
Error as follows:
test.cpp:33:45: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::thread(, std::reference_wrapper<TestTemp >)’
33 |         std::thread t1(function, std::ref(t)); // errors out
|                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/11/bits/std_thread.h:127:7: note: candidate: ‘template<class _Callable, class ... _Args, class> std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)’
127 |       thread(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)

Compiled with g++ with -std=c++20

Comment: The template parameters cannot be deduced in this scenario. You need to provide it manually here `function<int>`. Alternatively you could pass a object with the call operator implemented as template, but this is pretty close to the lambda...